# Pandas DataFrame query in sorting data

Tags: pandas

I am trying to sort a pandas dataframe. The data looks like-

| year | state | district | Party | rank | share in votes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2010 | haryana | kaithal | Winner | 1 | 40.12 |
| 2010 | haryana | kaithal | bjp | 2 | 30.52 |
| 2010 | haryana | kaithal | NOTA | 3 | 29 |
| 2010 | goa | panji | Winner | 3 | 10 |
| 2010 | goa | panji | INC | 2 | 40 |
| 2010 | goa | panji | BJP | 1 | 50 |
| 2013 | up | meerut | Winner | 2 | 40 |
| 2013 | up | meerut | SP | 1 | 60 |
| 2015 | haryana | kaithal | Winner | 2 | 15 |
| 2015 | haryana | kaithal | BJP | 3 | 35 |
| 2015 | haryana | kaithal | INC | 1 | 50 |

This data is for multiple states for multiple years.
In this dataset, there are multiple values for each district. I want to calculate the margin of share for each district in this manner. I have tried this, but not able to write fully. I am not able to write code for defining the margin of share and get a dataframe with only one (margin of share) value corresponding to each district instead of party wise shares.

```
for year in df['YEAR']:
 for state in df['STATE']:
    for district in df['DISTRICT']:
        for rank in df['RANK']:
            for party in df['PARTY']:
                if rank==1 and party=='WINNER':
```

then margin of share =Share of Winner-Share of party at rank 2. If share WINNER does not have rank 1 then Margin of Share= share of winner - share of party at rank 1.

I am basically trying to get this output-

```
|      year     |     state   |district| margin of share|
|---------------|-------------|--------|----------------|
|          2010    |     haryana       |kaithal| 9.6|
|          2010    |     goa       |panji| -40|
|          2010    |     up       |kaithal| -20|
|          2015   |     haryana      |kaithal| -35|
```

I wish to have create a different data frame with columns Year, State, District and margin of SHARE.

Comment: Can you share a reproducible example _as text_ (not image) and a clear expected output ?

Comment: please see if this version is better, or you need it in some other format

Comment: `df[(df['rank']==1) & (df.party=='WINNER')] `